# How to combine two lists python

Tags: python, list

I have two lists:

```
A =  ["a", "b", "c"]
B = ["H", "N"]
```

How to append values from second list to first, if I need to get this:

```
C = [["a","H"], ["a","N"], ["b", "H"], ["b", "N"], ["c", "H"], ["c", "N"]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import itertools

A = ["a", "b", "c"]
B = ["H", "N"]

print list(itertools.product(A, B))
# [('a', 'H'), ('a', 'N'), ('b', 'H'), ('b', 'N'), ('c', 'H'), ('c', 'N')]
```